# docker pull mysql error: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(

Tags: docker

i run 'sudo docker pull mysql' in centOS, but the error occurs:

failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 2): panic: regexp: Compile(`(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-]*)[a-z0-9]+)+)?-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]))+)?(?::[0-9]+)?/)?[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:(?:[._]|__|[-]*)[a-z0-9]+)+)?(?:(?:/[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:(?:[._]|__|[-]*)[a-z0-9]+)+)?)+)?`): error parsing regexp: unexpected ): `(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-]*)[a-z0-9]+)+)?-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]))+)?(?::[0-9]+)?/)?[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:(?:[._]|__|[-]*)[a-z0-9]+)+)?(?:(?:/[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:(?:[._]|__|[-]*)[a-z0-9]+)+)?)+)?`

[detail console pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kj5j.png)